# xetex complains about missing kanjix.map

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive

I've just installed TL2011 on Windows 7 and updated it from the net. The installation produced no errors and everything is fine - but now `xelatex` (and not `pdflatex` nor `lualatex`) ends every invocation with

> ** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".

I already did a `mktexlsr` and an `updmap --syncwithtrees`, but to no avail; there is still no `kanjix.map` and xetex wants it.

How do I get rid of this warning either by creating the file or removing it from `updmap.cfg`?

EDIT:
My `updmap.cfg` has these lines:

> KanjiMap ptex-@kanjiEmbed@.map
>   KanjiMap otf-@kanjiEmbed@.map
>   KanjiMap morisawa.map
>   KanjiMap otf-cktx.map

Comment: My `updmap.cfg` file has four entries labeled `KanjiMap`; does yours also?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, see above.

Comment: Do you use `updmap` or `updmap-sys`? In general the latter is recommended

Comment: @egreg: `updmap`. I just tried `updmap-sys` - no change.

Comment: You should first of all remove all files created by `updmap`, you should find them in `updmap.log` in the `.texlive2011` directory (or where they are created on Windows). What's the output of `kpsewhich updmap.cfg`?

Comment: @egreg: Done. Now it uses the one from `texlive/2011`. No change. It has the same lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2224/discussion-between-egreg-and-martin-schroder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys` results usually in head scratching or nightmares.

If one has administrative privileges, he/she should always rely on `updmap-sys`; `updmap` can be used by users that want to add personal map files that they aren't allowed to add system-wide, but must be run frequently to avoid that changes in the distribution may have adverse effects on the personal map tree.

This said, it happens sometimes that `updmap(-sys)` created files get out of synch. The best thing to try is

```
updmap-sys --syncwithtrees
updmap-sys
```

(assuming administrator privileges). This usually solves the issues.

A cause of errors in producing the correct map files is that during the process launched by `tlmgr`, some input map file can't be found. Trace of this can be found in the `tlmgr` log, in `TEXMFSYSVAR/web2c/tlmgr.log`, where `TEXMFSYSVAR` usually points to `texlive/2011/texmf-var`.

Comment: The problem was caused by a borked installation during which updmap failed. After that I never tried updmap(-sys) without arguments again. When I did, it fixed the problem.