# Font problems when using IPAexMincho

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am trying to run some fonts named IPAexMincho in latex under win 8 using MikTeX under TeXnic,
but I got error messages in regard to not being able to run Kanji map when I have the following valid settings (well, valid in the sense that I tried them out with other installed fonts and they just appeared to work find.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{IPAexMincho}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
helo word.
\end{document}
```

So when I do XeLaTeX , the resulting `pdf` does not even get generated.

The specific warning messages I get

```
xelatex> Warning Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".
xelatex> Warning Invalid glyph name index number : 12502 (>= 12495)
xelatex> Warning Invalid version 2.0 'post' tabe
xelatex> Error Could not obtain necessary font info
```

I of course obtain three other warnings XeLaTeX to `xparse/refedefine-command` but I don't think that those are crucial for this problem.

Yes, I know there are similar seemingly helpful posts here

[xetex complains about missing kanjix.map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41254/xetex-complains-about-missing-kanjix-map)

and some posts related to setting a new fonts in the main text. The problem though is that with other Japanese fonts, I seem not to have this problem.

Cheers,

T

Comment: Update: when i use option LUaLATEX--> PDF instead of XeLATEX-->PDF I seem to be able to generate the pdf. WHy ?  ANy hints, comments and suggestions are greatly appreaciated.

Comment: I am never able to get XeLaTex to work for me, but when I use LuaTeX, it works as well.  I always receive that same error about missing fonts.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as if you do not have the font correctly installed: looking for a map file indicates that XeTeX did not find it using the system font approach.

For me, everything works correctly if I do the following:

- Download the font from the [supplier](http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/ipaexfont/download.html#en)
- Unzip and install to the system fonts folder
- Tun your example using XeLaTeX from MiKTeX 2.9 or TeX Live 2013

I have Windows 7, but that should make very little difference here.

Comment: xelatex always loads the map files mentioned in dvipdfmx.cfg. And while it is a small nuisance that it warns that it couldn't find kanjix.map it is not related to problem (which sounds as if the font is defective).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do my instructions at least work for you? If so, I'll edit the answer to reflect the point you make but leave it here: if however it fails I'll remove.

Comment: Well they ask to accept some license so I didn't try. But reinstalling the font is certainly a good idea as the version used by the OP seems to be faulty.