# Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map". with MiKTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, compiling, warnings, mapping

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

When compiling this MWE with MiKTeX 2.9’s `xelatex`, I get the following warning:

```
** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".
```

The compilation runs through, no problems, but it bugs me that I get this message every time. It seems to come from Windows and not from `xelatex`, because it doesn’t appear in the log file, only in the command line. Here is the full command line output:

```
C:\Users\doncherry\Documents\LaTeX>xelatex bar.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\doncherry\Documents\LaTeX\bar.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, ancientgreek, french, germa
n, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, italian, latin, ngerman, ngerman-x-2013-05-26, r
ussian, spanish, swissgerman, ukenglish, usenglishmax, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\doncherry\Documents\LaTeX\bar.aux) [1]
(C:\Users\doncherry\Documents\LaTeX\bar.aux) )
** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".

Output written on bar.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on bar.log.
```

There are a few similar questions here, but none of them apply to this specific situation:

- [xelatex problem: Missing chars in TeXLive 2013 / \textfont XXX is undefined errors in miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/xelatex-problem-missing-chars-in-texlive-2013-textfont-xxx-is-undefined-erro) (Bottomline: It’s been fixed)
- [xetex complains about missing kanjix.map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41254/xetex-complains-about-missing-kanjix-map) (TeX Live-specific solution)
- [Font problems when using IPAexMincho](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123823/font-problems-when-using-ipaexmincho) (Using a special font)

Is there any way I can get rid of this warning? (Not just silence it, but cure the cause)

Comment: You need a kanjix.map (an empty, dummy map is quite ok) or you should change the dvipdfmx.cfg. http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2286/.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I should’ve checked the bugs first ... Feel free to add an answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a `kanjix.map` (an empty, dummy map is quite ok) or you should change the `dvipdfmx.cfg`. http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2286/

Comment: Would you mind exlain in more details how I can change dvipdfmx.cfg? Or where should I create a kanjix.map?

Comment: @newbie You can create an empty file "kanjix.map" in your editor and place it in your working directory.

Comment: @Ramaprakasha Thanks! That works... but I would be even more awesome if I could understand why.

Comment: This bug report explains you everything. http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2286/

Answer (score 4):

Note: The file `dvipdfmx.cfg` shouldn't be edited directly due to Miktex updating will repaire the file, but do the followings instead.

1. Open a Windows Command Line prompt and input `initexmf --edit-config-file dvipdfmx`, press `Enter`.
2. Append this line to the end of the opened file.

```
%%f kanjix.map
```