# Can I use Cambria font in TexStudio?

Tags: fonts, texstudio

I am new in LaTex. However, I am using document class Beamer with mode as presentation. I tried to change the main font. But do not find anyway! Can I use Cambria font in TexStudio? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the ttf (TrueType) Cambria font, you can use XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that since the default font theme in `beamer` switches to sans serif, one has to explicitly ask for a serif font using

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

or one of its variants (refer to the `beamer` manual).

Comment: Sorry, I am new in LaTex. Do I have to download and install XeLaTex?

Comment: @overwhelmed No; it should come with your LaTeX system (if its relatively updated). Your editor TeXstudio should have an option to choose which engine to use (there must be a menu showing things like pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex); choose xelatex to compile. All you need is to have the TrueType Cambria font; if your system doesn't already have it, there are numerous places in the web where you can download it.

Comment: For the record, I believe your screenshot is incorrect: it looks like Latin Modern Sans (a sans-serif font) instead of Cambria (a serif font).

Comment: @hftf You're right. Since the default font theme in beamer switches to sans serif, one has to explicitly ask for a serif font. I've updated my answer. Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Got it. It is in Option>Configure TexStudio>Build>Default Compiler. Now changed to XeLaTex. However, now I see new problem: ** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map". By the way, I am using Windows 7, and I have Cambria font at **C:\Windows\Fonts**. But no change of font to Cambria in my current document after using your codes. What should I do now?

Comment: @overwhelmed Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133591/3954.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. It works now. I appreciate it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Hi Gonzalo, I tried to comment in one of your post on **Justifying**. But I do not have enough reputation t comment. Here is my question: I have used your code \apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{} which destroyed \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference} for long bibliography. I get a header allowframebreaks and then no frame breaks at all. Can you please help?

Comment: @overwhelmed I suggest you to open a fresh new question, with a minimal version of the code you are using, clearly stating which is the problem and perhaps including a link to the mentioned post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13949/discussion-between-overwhelmed-and-gonzalo-medina)