# Strange temporary compilation error

Tags: errors, compiling

I get a very weird "error" just momentarily when I compile my document but when the compilation is finished it disappears and I have no errors or warnings. As you can see the "error" is huge and it keep going as there is a scrolling bar. This started happening the time that I used the `\usepackage{steinmetz}` and its command `\phase{}`. If I delete them then everything is ok. Why is this happenning and how can I fix it?

A MWE which has that problem when compiled:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{steinmetz}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\newcommand{\1}{\vspace{1cm}}

\newcommand{\rr}
{
\hrule

\vspace{0.3cm}
}

\begin{document}

$Y=|Y|\cdot e^{j\phi}=|Y|\phase{\phi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if this helps but these are the settings of my Texmaker:

[image]

After using the solution proposed by Ulrike Fischer all this "scary" warning disappears and in its place appears the following. It is of the same nature which means that it appears during compilation and disappears after the compilation is complete. What is that?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to compile with pdfTeX rather than TeX? (pdfLaTeX rather than LaTeX.)

Comment: I use XeLaTeX I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Steinmetz relies on pict2e, and imho there is no xetex driver in pict2e.

Comment: I get no error from a minimal document; and `p2e-xetex.def` is loaded. Tested with TeX Live 2014, 2013 and 2012.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Support for XeTeX in `pict2e` has been added in 2009, see [the file in TeX Live](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-xetex.def?revision=14620&view=markup)

Comment: I use Texmaker and every time I compile thaty problem happens again..

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code that shows the problem.

Comment: This [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Co0Fj.png) is what I get, with no error. By the way, `\everymath{\displaystyle}` is not recommendable.

Comment: Yes I know about the `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. I get that picture too as I said after the compile there is no errors. The errors exist only during compilation for a very short time.

Comment: @Adam You surely don't get the `\phase` symbol if you remove `steinmetz`.

Comment: Yes I checked multiple times.

Comment: @egreg: I could yesterday only look at the ctan site with my smartphone and so this see the xetex driver mentioned - and the warnings of xdvipdfmx are obviously a from a driver problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, steinmetz loads pict2e, and this package needs to load the correct driver. The loading of the driver is done in pict2e.cfg which on miktex is from 2005 (completly outdated) and so doesn't load the suitable driver for xetex but the dvips driver instead. In Tex Live there is no problem. Make a bug report on the miktex site. A work-around for the problem is to force pict2e to load the correct driver:

```
\usepackage[xetex]{pict2e}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
```

Comment: The kanjix-message is harmless but it shouldn't be there on an up-to-date system. See http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2286/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133591/couldnt-open-font-map-file-kanjix-map-with-miktex/133610#133610

Comment: I don't understand how to fix it :/

Comment: Run the update manager (in user and admin mode). Or ignore the message.

Comment: I updated and it didn't work :/